# AutoFS+LDAP doesn't work on boot (but does if I restart it)

Tags: automount, ldap

I currently use automount backed by LDAP. The LDAP server, and NFS mounts are hosted by a CentOS 5 machine, and when being used by other CentOS 5 (or Ubuntu 10.04) machines, everything works perfectly.

However, I'm having problems with Fedora 16. I've installed automount, and it comes up at boot. I can see that it is running in `ps aux` as well. When it's running from being launched by the startup scripts, I'm not able to access the NFS mounts in /home or /opt that normally would work.

If I run `service autofs restart`, then the mounts that I expect to exist, do exist.

I tend to think that this is occurring because automount is starting up before the network does, but I'm not sure how to verify this. Does anyone have any ideas on how to help with this?

Comment: Could be a timing problem. Have you looked at the log of the last boot what happens before?

Comment: I am having the same problem, however with internal disks which are only used occasionally. Autofs works fine after I restart it, but does not after boot (even though I see it running). Since this is an old question - did you find a solution meanwhile?

Comment: No, not really. I imagine I either stopped using Fedora, or I added a line to /etc/init.d/rc.local to restart it (since that script happens relatively late in the boot).

Comment: have a look at this answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38678/nis-and-autofs-manual-restart-after-a-reboot/183258#183258

Might help